# unable to create zip file in java useing java.util.zip, getting archive is corrupt

Tags: java

I am able to create the zip folder with some pdf. but when I am unziping it is getting archive is corrupt. 
here is the code I tried.

```
//create byte buffer
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ZipOutputStream zout = new ZipOutputStream(bos);

            zout.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry("first.pdf"));
            int length;
            //con.getInputStream() is the inputstream
            while((length = con.getInputStream().read(buffer)) > 0)
            {
                zout.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
            zout.closeEntry();
            resp.setContentType(CONTENT_TYPE_ZIP);
            resp.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=first.zip");
            resp.getOutputStream().write(bos.toByteArray());
            pdfMsOfficeCacheHeaderUtil.process(request, resp);
            resp.flushBuffer();                
            zout.flush();
            zout.finish();
            zout.close();
            bos.close();
```

please let me know where I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution.

```
            //create byte buffer
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ZipOutputStream zout = new ZipOutputStream(bos);

            zout.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry("first.pdf"));
            int length;

            while((length = content.getInputStream().read(buffer)) > 0)
            {
                zout.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
             zout.flush();
            zout.finish();
            bos.flush();
            resp.setContentType(CONTENT_TYPE_ZIP);
            resp.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename= first.zip");
            resp.getOutputStream().write(bos.toByteArray());
            pdfMsOfficeCacheHeaderUtil.process(request, resp);
            resp.flushBuffer();               
            zout.close();
            bos.close();
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You're flushing, finishing and closing your `zout` **after** you've written the contents of `bos` to the response stream.

First finish writing the zip data, **then** write the data to the response so it'll be correct.